# Dataframeにネストした辞書を一つずつ追加していく方法

Tags: pandas, json

下記1、2の処理で辞書をDataframeに一行ずつ追加していく方法を教えてください。

1. 下記ocのvalueを更新
2. oc_dfに一行ずつvalueを追加
   1、2を繰り返してoc_dfを更新
   oc_dfに追加する行はリングバッファのように更新して最大10行としたいのですが中々うまくいきません。

```
PTPSYNC = "hoge"
SWD1 = "delay"
SWD2 = "offset"
TIME = "timedate"

oc = {
      TIME: '',
      PTPSYNC+str(1): {SWD1: 0, SWD2: 0},
      PTPSYNC+str(2): {SWD1: 0, SWD2: 0}
      }

oc_df = pd.json_normalize(oc)
```

希望するdataframeは以下のイメージです

```
timedate           hoge1.delay  hoge1.offset  hoge2.delay  hoge2.offset
1970-1-1_12:00;00           30            32           23            22
1970-1-1_12:00;01           31            32           24            21
1970-1-1_12:00;02           11            22           24            22
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: 辞書を1行ずつDataFrameにする方法がわからなかったので、一旦辞書を複数行生成した後にまとめてpd.json_normalize ()でDataFrameを生成することにしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

普通に追加するならこのようにできます。
しかし処理速度は遅いはずなのでやめたほうがよいでしょう

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for _ in range(3):
    # ここで oc_df 作成しておいて
    df = df.append(oc_df)
display(df)
```

解決されたようですが, 辞書を複数行用意し (DataFrame作るのなら)一挙に作るほうが速いはずです

```py
# どのように生成するのか不明なので, 順次に行う場合 ↓
oc = {
      TIME: '',
      PTPSYNC+str(1): {SWD1: 0, SWD2: 0},
      PTPSYNC+str(2): {SWD1: 0, SWD2: 0}
      }
oc1 = {
      TIME: '',
      PTPSYNC+str(1): {SWD1: 1, SWD2: 1},
      PTPSYNC+str(2): {SWD1: 1, SWD2: 1}
      }
oc2 = {
      TIME: '',
      PTPSYNC+str(1): {SWD1: 2, SWD2: 2},
      PTPSYNC+str(2): {SWD1: 2, SWD2: 2}
      }
lst = []
lst.append(oc)
lst.append(oc1)
lst.append(oc2)
oc_df = pd.json_normalize(lst)
```

Comment: 「遅い」と言っても, 数件程度ならもちろん速いです。数百・数千件それ以上になると, 重く感じると思います